# Android complex recycler view design

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using recyclerview in my app. The adapter also contains recyclerview. The problem is there is too much space between each items. I am not using space item decoration in the parent recycler view. Please find attached screenshot
[image: Extra space]

Comment: question is not clear ..

Comment: Make your custom layout parent layout to _wrap_content_

Comment: your code is not here, what have you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your parent layout of custom row file to `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`.